# How to make a random text rotate on hover on a button, as like as google "I am feeling lucky button" works can anyone help me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, animation

I was searching some resource of random text rotation on hover in button and stop with a new text. As like as Google 'I am feeling lucky' button works. https://www.google.com/  Can anyone help me in making something like this?

Regards

Comment: ca search https://developers.google.com/maps/

Comment: Check out this Codepen http://codepen.io/mattboldt/pen/ELabe

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#hvrButton').hover(function() {
  $('#hvrButton').val("I am Very Happy");
});
```

```css
.btnCustom {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #03A9F4;
  color: white;
}

.btnCustom:hover {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #0425f9;
  color: white;
  font-family: cursive;
  -webkit-animation-name: btnRotate;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
}

@-webkit-keyframes btnRotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -200deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -200deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="hvrButton" type="button" value="I am feeling lucky" class="btnCustom" />
```

Comment: Hello Kinjal Akhani,  Thank you for your response. But how I can show new text on rotation. I mean after hover the button a new text need to appear instead of previous one. Can you help with this too?

Comment: Hello Munna_695, Try this code, in this, on hover new Text "I am very Happy" will be appear replacing "I am feeling lucky" Value in Button.

Comment: @KinjalAkhani i think you didn't get his question clearly. You coded something else

Comment: I agree with Deepak Yadav. I appreciate Kinjal Akahni's willingness to help me. But it's not what I actually I want. I want the text to rotate on hover something like a slot machine.